# How to convert the array variables into string

Tags: php, arrays, string

Currently my Array looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0]=>Nagpur
    [1]=>Pune 
)
```

Now I want this array in the following format:

```
'Nagpur', 'Pune'
```

Comment: Use `$str = "'".implode("','", $array)."'"`

Comment: Just write echo "'".implode(",",arrayName)."'";

Answer (score 0):

If you want the `'` included in your string, use `implode("', '",$array)` if you don't want them, however, just use `implode(", ",$array)`.

Answer (score 0):

try php [implode](http://pk1.php.net/implode):

```
$array = array( [0]=>Nagpur [1]=>Pune )
$comma_separated = implode("',", $array);
```